# Why my indexOf value is not returning the right result?

Tags: java, string, methods, indexof

I am writing this little section for a program I'm gonna write for initials of a name in java, and I need to determine the position of each space in it to be able to choose the initials. I'm testing it to make sure the spaces are been seen in the right position in the line, but for some reason, the position always comes wrong! Please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter full name:");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    int space = name.indexOf(" ");
    int space1 = name.indexOf(" ", space) + space+1;
    int space2 = name.indexOf(" ", space1) + space1+1;
    int space3 = name.indexOf(" ", space2) + space2+1;
    int space4 = name.indexOf(" ", space3) + space3+1;
    int space5 = name.indexOf(" ", space4) + space4+1;
    System.out.println(space + " " + space1 + " " + space2 + " " + space3 + " " + space4);      
  }
}
```

My idea using this line was to count up to each part of the line space that shows up after the last one and add 1 because java starts counting at 0.

> (" ", space1) + space1+1;

Basically, if the name is "Jeff Luiz Jeff Luiz" the first space is at **4** and the next one is at **9**, so it would the **4**, then proceed to count after this space, starting at 0, which would find 4 again(because Luiz has the same amount of letters), sum up with the last space number to keep track of the real position(then it would be **8**), and finally sum up with 1 because of how java works, and so on. When I ran these 4 words I found the result **4 9 19 19 19**. Does anyone know what is the problem with my code?

Comment: what is your expected output for `"Jeff Luiz Jeff Luiz"`?

Comment: To get the index of the second space you need to use `int space1 = name.indexOf(" ", space + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
int space1 = name.indexOf(" ", space) + space+1;
```

with

```
int space1 = name.indexOf(" ", space + 1);
```

because [`String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Arvind Kumar Avinash";
        int space = name.indexOf(" ");
        int space1 = name.indexOf(" ", space + 1);
        System.out.println(space + ", " + space1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6, 12
```